# In Java sometimes method parameters act like passed by reference, even though they are not. what method are they passed by?

Tags: java, parameter-passing

In Java sometimes method parameters act like passed by reference, even though they are not. 
what method are they passed by?

I know java is always passed by value. But is it possible that it could act like pass by reference

Comment: The reference variable(usually an instance of a class) stores the memory address of the object, not the object itself. So, if you pass an object as a parameter, the method copies the 'address' of the variable. That's why it looks like passing by reference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1
I think looking at this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

All parameters are passed by value.

Visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: I think he knows that.

Comment: @March3April4 your making an assumption that he knows.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a correct argument..